# Rule space before class variables for prettier

Tags: prettier

Which rules should I use to add extra space before class variable using prettier?

Current state:

```
export class TestClassName {
    foo: number;
```

Expected state:

```
export class TestClassName {
    
    foo: number;
```

Answer (score 1):

Prettier doesn't have "rules". Rules are an ESLint thing. You probably confused the two tools. Prettier is an opinionated formatter. It doesn't allow customizing minor things like that.